# Github-like inline code styling

Tags: html, css

I'm using the [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/) library to "syntax-highlight" my code snippets.
A snippet can be a code block:

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-java">
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
  </code>
</pre>
```

or a simple inline code:

```
Type <code>git log</code> in your prompt!
```

I'm trying to mimic the github-way to style these two snippet categories, e.g. see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git).

This is my current (broken) CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/hdy44/2/

Does exist a way to apply the `border-radius` only to `code` elements that are not children of `pre` elements?

Of course I can add a custom class (e.g. `inline`) to the inline `code` elements and then apply the `border-radius` only to `pre` and to `.inline`, but this would require more typing.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hdy44/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working copy: http://jsfiddle.net/hdy44/3/

```
pre {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #BCBEC0;
    background: #F1F3F5;
    font:12px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale  Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace
}

code {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #BCBEC0;
    padding: 2px;
    font:12px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale  Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace
}

pre code {
    border-radius: 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
    border: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    font:12px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale  Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace
}
```

You need to create CSS for the code tag that is used with pre. then override the border radius and border.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by setting  the border-radius for all code elements and then override it for those that appear within a pre element, something like this:

```
code{
 border-radius: 25px;
}

pre code{
 border-radius: 0px;
}
```

because the second css snippet is more specific it will override the first.